# How would I create a RouteModule in Angular 2 without forRoot

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I am working on going through the Style guide for Angular 2 and I happened upon [this line](https://angular.io/styleguide#02-12)

> Do end the filename of a RoutingModule with -routing.module.ts.

I haven't had luck finding anything on routing module examples so I went to Papa's blog. There I found this line...

> The forRoot() function should only be used for creating the root modules' routes. When we get to child modules and routes, we'll use other techniques that we'll see in later posts.

So how do I create a RouteModule that isn't using forRoot like suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an example here...

https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/ngmodule/ts/app/contact/contact-routing.module.ts